# Getting extra data in MYSQL count query

Tags: php, mysql

Hi all i've had help from bluefleet (BF) with a mysql query which i've now put in a php file, the query works fine but i find i need to get extra data as well as the count, so what i need is when a match is found i need to look up the username in table tview3.

Whichever table the ip match is found there will be a column called UID, in the table tview3 there will also be a column called USERNAME, what i'd like to do is get the username(s) for the matches and then use them in a text file.

I have to state i'm a complete newbie at this, all help is appreciated

```
$myquery= "select sum(total)
from
(
    SELECT count(*) as total
    FROM " .TABLE_PREFIX."tview v
    where v.ipaddress = '$ips'
    union all
    SELECT count(*) as total
    FROM " .TABLE_PREFIX."tview2 v1
    where v1.ipaddress = '$ips'
    union all
    SELECT count(*) as total
    FROM " .TABLE_PREFIX."tview3 v3
    where v3.ipaddress = '$ips'
) src";

 $result = mysql_query($myquery);
    $rowCount = mysql_num_rows($result);
    If($rowCount !=0){
       echo "NOT EMPTY";
    }else{
      echo "EMPTY";
    }
   mysql_free_result($result);

$UAM = strtoupper($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
$ips = strtoupper($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$fp = fopen("logtext.txt", "a");
$DateOfRequest = date('m-d-Y H:i:s');

fwrite($fp, "$DateOfRequest . \nMatched Member: . $username . \nWith User Agent:  . $UAM . \n\nIP: . $ips . \n\n");
```

So i'd like to populate a variable **$username** with the username(s) where the matches were found.

Regards,
Silo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

`SELECT count(*) as total`

to

```
 SELECT count(*) as total, username
```

Then you could do something like:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$username = $row['username'];
```

Hope that helps.  Also check out this question for a bit more detail: [How do I find the most common result in a column in my MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739143/how-do-i-find-the-most-common-result-in-a-column-in-my-mysql-table)

Comment: Maybe. It's unclear if the OP knows how *aggregate* functions work in SQL. He might want to add a `GROUP BY` like `SELECT username, count(*) as total FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."tview v where v.ipaddress = '$ips' GROUP BY username`.

Comment: The answer you link to shows the `GROUP BY`, but you don't show it here.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, i am a complete newbie, can i just add what you've given to my php code just above the $UAM and then use $username in the write to text file?

Comment: Also, USERNAME only appears in the last table we check however UID appears in ALL three tables, so if it found a match in table 2 at row 3 then lookup that UID in table 3 and add the USERNAME to the variable, do this for all 3 tables that we're looking at, so eventuall $username may look like this: Jon Doe Jane Doe Jack Doe, does that make sense on what im attempting to do?

Comment: Any further light on this guys?