# mysql - find most popular two column value combination and sort by popularity

Tags: php, mysql

In a table named inventory, I have two columns named food and brand.  Here is an example of the table contents:

```
food       |        brand
----------------------------
cookies    | Pepperidge Farm
cookies    | Pepperidge Farm
goldfish   | Pepperidge Farm
cookies    | Oreo
crackers   | Ritz
goldfish   | Pepperidge Farm
crackers   | Ritz
crackers   | Ritz
goldfish   | Pepperidge Farm
goldfish   | Pepperidge Farm
```

I am trying to write a mysql query that will pull the three most popular item, brand combinations from the table.  The trouble I'm having is that the brand can have more than one item, but I want to take a count of the most popular brand AND item, not the most popular brand.  So in the table above, the query would return the following in order of most popular to least popular (limited to three results):

```
goldfish | Pepperidge Farm
crackers | Ritz
cookies  | Pepperidge Farm
```

Comment: What's your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: check this one, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739143/how-do-i-find-the-most-common-result-in-a-column-in-my-mysql-table

Comment: @Strawberry - The primary key is an ID field that auto-increments.

Comment: @Fallen - I saw that and it's not what I want.  That counts the number of times that the user is found in that table's column, and then sorts according to the most popular.  It helps, though.  I am looking to do something similar but with two columns.

Comment: @Jen View my posted answer with fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82806/6)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `Rows`, FOOD, BRAND
   FROM `foods`
     GROUP BY FOOD, BRAND
     ORDER BY `Rows` DESC
```